# Django loses value if choices is dynamic

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a following problem.
Let's say w have a model with column *date* defined like this:

```
date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Fueling Date", choices=generate_dates())
```

Definition of *generate_dates()* functions is like this:

```
def generate_dates(days_in_past=10):
    """
    Generate list of dates from today to *days_in_past* days into past.

    Generated elements of the list are in format required by django models.
    Each element is 2-element tuple:
        (datetime.date, datetime.date)

    :param days_in_past:
        Int number of days into past.

    :return:
        List of tuples consist of two datetime.date elements.
        Len of generated list equals *days_in_past* + 1 (because of today's day).
    """
    dates = pd.date_range(
        start=pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime.today()).date() - pd.offsets.Day(days_in_past),
        end=pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime.today()).date(),
        freq="D").tolist()[::-1]
    dates = [(x.date(), x.date()) for x in dates]
    return dates
```

Function *generate_dates* returns list of last x dates (so its dynamic, every day it moves one day forward).

I see in django admin, that if I have old insertion of this model (old means older than the latest date returned by *generate_dates* function), for values in column *date*  there is no date displayed.

In database it is stored, so there is no data leakage, but django displays for this "----" instead of real date.
Once I change *generate_dates* to return list of dates that contains the old one (I extend the period), date in django admin appears again.

How can I avoid that?
Let's say I entered data into the model 1 of January, *generate_dates* returns only 10 dates.
We have 20 of January and I still want to have date "1 of January" being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, you would want to create a custom admin form for your model. It's a little work, but the docs explain it really well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options